# Find 4chan post linking to your website?

Tags: statistics, referrer

I looked in my visitor statistics and saw that some people were coming from `boards.4chan.org`. Hmm, interesting. I'd like to see that post... Is there any way to find it?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have access, search your server's access logs for `4chan` and the entry will include the URL. You could also try searching for your site with a site specific search on google `yoursearchterm site:4chan.org`.